# sfDoctrineGenerator Delete does not work

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

Lately, I have been exploring the sfDoctrineGenerator of Symfony for my backend interface.  The problem is this:

I am using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for user management.  The sfGuardUser module uses sfDoctrineGenerator.  All of the functions needed (delete, edit, add) are working. So far so good.

I then created a new module using this [link](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12) as reference.  The add and edit functions now work but I can not make delete (both batch and single delete) work.  I tried to explicitly add it under the batch actions, but it still does not work. It says that it has already deleted showing a flash message success, but no element was deleted.  Can someone point me to the right direction where the problem could have originated?

Here is a copy of my generator.yml

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           News
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          news
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~

      fields:  
        news: {label: Announcement}
        created_at: {label: Date Published}
        updated_at: {label: Date Updated}
        user_id: {label: Author}
        user_name: {label: Author}

      list:    
        title:          Announcements List
        display:        [=title, created_at, updated_at, user_name]
        sort:           [created_at, desc]
        max_per_page:   10
        batch_actions:
          _delete:    ~

      filter: 
        display:  [title, user_id]

      form:   
        class:    NewsForm

      edit:    
        title:    Editing Announcement "%%title%%"

      new:     
        title:    New Announcement
```

If you need something else from me, please do not hesitate to comment.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the request header as viewed in Chrome:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/inventory_dev.php/news
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ja_purity_tpl=ja_purity; fontSize=100; __atuvc=312|19; JSESSIONID=9DDD204812F0C53A8B3D33B89BF7A7C8; matciis=ha6l8ci8h3i2bp696e4h33vig2; symfony=ld2qept3j5cddjsb16qie098u3
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/inventory_dev.php/news
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 30 May 2012 08:30:02 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.8
```

Comment: Did you track the sql query that might delete the row ?

Comment: I am sorry. What do you suggest on how I should do that? I tried accessing the site via the fronend_dev.php controller after the delete button but all queries are SELECT's.

Comment: I'm asking you to check the [queries from MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/logging-queries-with-mysql/) (if you use it) to see the `DELETE` query when you press the delete link in the backend. So you will be able to test the query in phpMyAdmin (for example) to see the SQL error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the D'OH moments in life.

The problem was that in my schema.yml, I specified:

```
actAs: { Timestampable: ~ , SoftDelete: ~ }
```

This means that when I delete the element, it only adds the timestamp to it instead of physically deleting it.  I removed the SoftDelete from the configuration and the problem was fixed.

Maybe there should be a functionality in sfDoctrineGenerator to support SoftDelete?